# OSX - Schedule programs to start at night, close in morning

Tags: macos, dropbox, scheduled-tasks

On Mac OSX, is there a program or method I could use to start an application (say Dropbox) at around 9pm at night and then close the application in the morning (say 9am).

I've found Dropbox is making my machine very slow, so if I could open it when I'm not at work and let it sync over night and then close when I get back into the office that would be great.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Automator is another, possibly simpler, option. You can even schedule recurring automator tasks via the Calendar app. The task you're looking to accomplish should be very easy. You could make two one-line automator scripts, 1) Launch Application, and 2) Quit Application and schedule them via Calendar as recurring events every day.

Answer (score 0):

I think cron could be a good option for this task. Using cron you can schedule tasks to be performed at a certain time. The following link shows you the command to open an application.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86465/how-can-root-launch-a-regular-mac-application-from-a-cron-job-in-etc-crontab

That said I'm very surprised that Dropbox is causing such noticeable slow downs. Perhaps it could be something else?

Comment: I have actually found a solution today which I will post, it's an app called Power Manager, which allows you to launch an application at a time. It also allows you to run a script at a specific time too, so I have set up a script to kill the Dropbox app.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Power Manager Pro](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/professional/), I was able to launch the application at 21:00 hours and then run a script at 08:00 hours which killed the program, this script is simply `killall Dropbox`.

Comment: Now legacy software. As of November 2020 only supports macOS 10.10 – 10.13